# MYSQL query so it also returns values if has no value in the other table

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi guys in the code below you can see what my JSON returns.

```
{"lifehacks":[{
   "id":"2",
 "URLtoImage":"http:\/\/images.visitcanberra.com.au\/images\/canberra_hero_image.jpg",
   "title":"dit is nog een test",
   "author":"1232123",
   "score":"2",
   "steps":"fdaddaadadafdaaddadaaddaadaaaaaaaaaaa","category":"Category_2"}]}
```

What the JSON returns is fine. The only problem is it is only displaying lifehacks if it has one like or more. So what should I change about my Query so it would display lifehacks without likes aswell.

```
//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("admin_nakeitez",$db);

//Replace * in the query with the column names.
$result = mysql_query("select idLifehack, urlToImage, title, Lifehack.Users_fbId, idLifehack, steps, Categorie, count(Lifehack_idLifehack) as likes from Lifehack, Likes where idLifehack = Lifehack_idLifehack AND idLifehack > " . $_GET["id"]. " group by idLifehack;", $db);  




//Create an array
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['idLifehack'];
    $row_array['URLtoImage'] = $row['urlToImage'];
    $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
    $row_array['author'] = $row['Users_fbId'];
    $row_array['score'] = $row['likes'];
    $row_array['steps'] = $row['steps'];
    $row_array['category'] = $row['Categorie'];



    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo "{\"lifehacks\":";
echo json_encode($json_response);
echo "}";

//Close the database connection
fclose($db);
```

I hope my problem is clear like this. Thank you in advance I can't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` here. Your query has an `INNER JOIN`.

```
select
  idLifehack,
  urlToImage,
  title,
  Lifehack.Users_fbId,
  idLifehack,
  steps,
  Categorie,
  count(Lifehack_idLifehack) as likes
from Lifehack
left join Likes on idLifehack = Lifehack_idLifehack
where idLifehack > whatever
group by idLifehack;
```

There's an excellent explanation of the different join types [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

A couple additional points...

---

Use prepared statements in your PHP. Your code is wide-open to SQL Injection, which has ruined careers and led to millions of innocent people having their personal information stolen. There are plenty of web sites showing how to do this so I won't go into it here, though I'll say my favorite is [bobby-tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com/).

---

Avoid the implicit join anti-pattern in your queries. This is an implicit join:

```
FROM a, b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Use explicit joins instead; they separate your join logic from your filtering (`WHERE`) logic:

```
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thank you I know about the unsafe part but its school project and the server does not understand PDO or MYSQL but thanks for saying it